# Android EditText issue in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-6.0-marshmallow

Having an issue with my app when trying to run it on an Acer Iconia One 10 tablet that is loaded with Marshmallow 6.0. This app works perfectly on a Samsung Galaxy Tablet running Android 4.2.2.
The main view consists of a series of TextViews and EditTexts where the user can enter information. The fields need to be able to accept either text or numerals. I use the field `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` to accomplish this. It has always worked. However, with 6.0, I'm getting a weird behavior that I believe has to be some type of version issue. If I type in letters everything is fine. But when I try to enter a string like "Route 169", the numbers will not appear. If I type in "Route169" it puts the numbers up there. It seems that once I put in a , the EditText stops accepting input. I have tried every variation of `android:input="someInputType"` that could possibly work for me and nothing has fixed it. I also tried the `android:digits="ABC....0123 "` solution. 
Here is my EditText definition:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/highwayNameEditText"
android:text="*****"
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
android:layout_below="@+id/highwayNameTextView"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/highwayNameTextView"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/highwayNameTextView" />
```

It is within a ScrollView using a RelativeLayout. I have also tried adding a key event listener to no avail. 
Logcat shows the following messages when the keyboard character is successfully transfered to the EditText:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 4 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 261, 15, 19
```

When the entry fails, the following appears in logcat:

```
View Root Impl: **[ANR Warning]Input routeing takes more than 6000ms** 
Input event delivered to android.view.View Root Impl$Early PostImeInputStage
Input event delivered to android.view.View RootImpl$Native PostImeInputStage
Input event delivered to android.view.View Root Impl$ View PostImeInputStage
Input event delivered to android.view.View Root Impl$ Synthetic InputStage
```

The sequence repeats.
**Note:** I have removed time, date, and location information from the output to make it more readable.

As you can see, the system saw a key press event. The character did not make it to the Edit Text string. There also appears to possibly be a timeout issue of some kind. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Try installing a different IME (soft keyboard) from the Play Store or F-Droid. See if the problem recurs with it. If not, then then problem is with the stock IME on that device, and I doubt that there is much that you can do about it.

Comment: Do you try AppCompatEditText support class instead ?

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded SwiftKey and that works. However, during the process I had to create a Google account on the tablet. The standard keyboard worked fine during the sign up process. Could there be something about my minVersion or some other issue that makes the keyboard wonky?

Comment: "Do you try AppCompatEditText support class instead ?" I have not tried that. I would prefer to not have a different compile for the 10 inch device if possible.

Comment: I tried AppCompat. Didn't solve the issue.